# What is 00100110 + 01010111?

Tags: binary

So basically I am doing this thing and it says what is *00100110 + 01010111*.

00100110 = ***k*** in binary
01010111 = ***X*** in binary

I naturally went to wikipedia and searched Alphabet. This gave me a grid where it showed me what letter corresponded to what number.

***k*** is **11**

***X*** is **24**

I added these together to get 35. I put in 35,1124,2411,13 and all of those in binary.  These were ***ALL*** incorrect somehow.

I do not know what else it could be!

Comment: I suspect it's asking you to literally just [add the two binary numbers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=binary+addition), rather than convert them to ASCII characters, etc.

Comment: You can refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Addition)

Comment: Add the two numbers together. 1+1 = 0 carry a 1. Or convert to decimal and add, then re-convert to binary.  01111101  Check out http://www.calculator.net/binary-calculator.html

Comment: Just add them up 00100110 + 01010111 = 0111 1101 binary = 125 decimal

Comment: Thanks that was it Oliver and Melle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Characters of the alphabet are often used as a way of tagging a number so it can be easily referred to, so if the problem is not specifically asking you to guess a character out of it, the answer would be 125 in binary.

100110 = 38
1010111 = 87

100110 + 1010111 = 1111101 = 125